# How to download files from a txt file containing target list recursively?

Tags: file, ssh, command-line, download, wget

I want to download files using ssh commands, there's a text file containing all urls of files I want to download, The problem is that I want these files to be downloaded each one in their respective folder.
For example, Here is some sample links in that txt file:

```
http://dl.example.com/2016/06/file1.zip
http://dl.example.com/2016/06/softwares/file2.zip
http://dl.example.com/2013/09/anotherfile.mp3
http://dl.example.com/movies/samplemovie.mkv
```

I want these files to be downloaded in this schema :

```
root/2016/06/file1.zip
root/2016/06/softwares/file2.zip
root/2013/09/anotherfile.mp3
root/movies/samplemovie.mkv
```

I mean I want this command to not only download the file, But also create the directory of that file exactly on my server.
How can I do that ?

Comment: How is ssh relevant to downloading files from http urls?

Comment: Something like wget @Kenster